# Dockerfile Permission denied during RUN apt-get update

Tags: linux, unix, dockerfile

I am getting permission denied on RUN apt-get update within my Dockerfile , this is  the content of the file:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN whoami 
RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get -y upgrade && \ 
apt-get install -y sudo
```

when I try running RUN whoami at the top, I see 'root' printed to screen. I tried searching online but nothing seems relevant to this error message.

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to read /var/cache/apt/ - opendir (13: Permission denied)
```

I noticed my Docker version seems out-dated but I ran `sudo yum update` and it tells me everything is already up to date.

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-206.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Wed May 19 02:56:06 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-206.git7d71120.el7_9.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7d71120/1.13.1
 Built:           Wed May 19 02:56:06 2021
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

VS what I see on Docker website:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:21:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: Are you building image from normal user account ? Or as a root ?  By default  Unix socket is owned by the user root

Comment: i followed post-installation instructions from Docker website to use non-root. Is that the reason?

Comment: did you add current user to docker group ?

Comment: yup i used that `groupadd` command. I am able to run docker without prefixing it with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

check this one
first run your command with sudo
if you get error check position permission

Comment: hi hadi.kianersi, thanks for suggestion. when I run sudo, it gives me, the same error. This is the command I ran: `sudo build -t tag-name --build-arg UNAME=uname --build-arg VERSION=1_4_1 -f Dockerfile-base .`

Answer (score 0):

Previously I set:

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false'
to
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false -g /mnt/tmp/'
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` based on a suggestion in a docker forum post which solved an 'out of space' error when building docker images. But I didn't realise the new docker tmpdir had no permissions, thus giving me the permission denied error. Finally I just increased the size of the /var/lib/docker directory (default):

```
sudo lvextend -L +8GB /dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv
sudo xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv
```

and I was then able to happily build images.